# Bean property 'channelIdentifierMap' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm using Spring integration 4.0 and I tried to create a payloadTypeRouter object that has 2 message channels - one for String payloads and one for Integer payloads. I'm trying to do so by the following java code:

```
package MessageExamples;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.router.PayloadTypeRouter;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
QueueChannel q_channel1=new QueueChannel();
QueueChannel q_channel2=new QueueChannel();
ApplicationContext ctx= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringIntegration.xml");
PayloadTypeRouter r= (PayloadTypeRouter) ctx.getBean("payloadTypeRouter");
}}
```

With the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">
    <bean id="payloadTypeRouter"
    class="org.springframework.integration.router.PayloadTypeRouter">
    <property name="channelIdentifierMap">
    <map>
    <entry key="java.lang.String" value-ref="stringChannel"/>
    <entry key="java.lang.Integer" value-ref="integerChannel"/>
    </map>
    </property>
    </bean>
    <int:channel id="stringChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="integerChannel"/>
    </beans>
```

When I try to run it I get the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'payloadTypeRouter' defined in class path resource [SpringIntegration.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'channelIdentifierMap' of bean class [org.springframework.integration.router.PayloadTypeRouter]: Bean property 'channelIdentifierMap' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.

I've noticed that AbstractMessageRouter doesn't contain a map setter in Spring Integration version 4.0 although it has one in previous versions. How can I configurate this kind of router?

Comment: Hmm, the docs for Spring Integration 4.0 still say to use the `channelIdentintifierMap` property, even though it's not there any more. Looks like a bug in the docs to me: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-payloadtyperouter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property was renamed to `channelMapping` [several years ago](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/73c9876) (in 2.1); I have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3590) to fix the documentation.

Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you don't need the last channels definitions. According to the docs, you only need:

```
<bean id="payloadTypeRouter"
      class="org.springframework.integration.router.PayloadTypeRouter">
    <property name="channelIdentifierMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="java.lang.String" value-ref="stringChannel"/>
            <entry key="java.lang.Integer" value-ref="integerChannel"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Or, an equivalent definition:

```
<int:payload-type-router input-channel="routingChannel">
    <int:mapping type="java.lang.String" channel="stringChannel" />
    <int:mapping type="java.lang.Integer" channel="integerChannel" />
</int:payload-type-router>
```

Comment: but still, what if I want to test it from a java class with a main function?